# Rodar duas funções em loop ao mesmo tempo

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Gostaria de rodar duas funções ao mesmo tempo em Python, segue meu código:

```
import socket
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import ThreadedFTPServer 
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer



class MyHandler(FTPHandler):

    def on_connect(self):
        print(str(self.remote_ip)+':'+str(self.remote_port), 'se conectou!')

    def on_disconnect(self):
        # do something when client disconnects
        pass

    def on_login(self, username):
        # do something when user login
        pass

    def on_logout(self, username):
        # do something when user logs out
        pass

    def on_file_sent(self, file):
        # do something when a file has been sent
        pass

    def on_file_received(self, file):
        # do something when a file has been received
        pass

    def on_incomplete_file_sent(self, file):
        # do something when a file is partially sent
        pass

    def on_incomplete_file_received(self, file):
        # remove partially uploaded files
        os.remove(file)

def ftp_server():
    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
    authorizer.add_user('user', '', '.', perm='elradfmwMT')
    handler = MyHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer
    server = ThreadedFTPServer(('10.1.1.127', 21), handler)
    server.serve_forever()

def socket_server():
    host = '' 
    port = 7000 
    addr = (host, port) 
    serv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serv_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
    serv_socket.bind(addr) 
    serv_socket.listen(10) 
    print('aguardando conexao')
    con, cliente = serv_socket.accept() 
    print('conectado')
    print('aguardando mensagem')
    recebe = con.recv(1024) 
    print('mensagem recebida:'+ recebe)
    serv_socket.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ftp_server()
    socket_server()
    #Preciso que as duas funções acima funcionem ao mesmo tempo (ou seja, as duas 
    #fiquem ouvindo novas 
    #conexões, tanto FTP, como Socket, e sempre que vier uma conexão, a conexão 
    #deve ser devidamente 
    #atendida e tratada)
```

Como fazer isso da forma certa e mais simples possível? Achei vários tutoriais mais nenhum trás a simplicidade que eu quero para fazer isso.

Answer (score 3):

A ideia inicial de threading é bem simples - e para o que vocẽ quer fazer aí: duas tarefas de I/O não relacionadas, cada uma na sua thread, é talvez um dos cenários em que fica mais simples de manter.

No caso é só criar dois objetos do tipo Thread, e o principal argumento para esses objetos é *qual* função vai rodar naquela thread (essa é a função que vai iniciar a thread: claro que ela pode chamar outras funções de lá de dentro).

Até daria para organizar tudo dentro do `if __name__ == ...`  aí - mas é melhor colocar essa lógica em uma função também:

```py
import threading

...

def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=ftp_server)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=socket_server)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Perceba que na chamada para threading.Thread você não pode *chamar* a função,
(colocando os `()` depois de `ftp_server()`) - você passa a própria função como parâmetro. Se colocar `()` o Python vai chamar a função para tentar passar o valor de retorno dela para criar a classe `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

facinho ^^ você pode usar Thread

faz assim:

```
import threading
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # e na hora de chamar as funcoes:
    x = threading.Thread(target=ftp_server)
    x.start()
    y = threading.Thread(target=socket_server)
    y.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        #isso aki he so pra nao sair do cod emquanto ta tudo rodando
```